# ORACLE SQL:Can someone explain me the difference between these two?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm a student and this is my first year of learning Oracle SQL. On the exam, I used this code:

```
SELECT department_id,MAX(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING INSTR(TO_CHAR(department_id),'5')!=1 AND MAX(salary)<1000;
```

and the professor said that I should be using something like

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, MAX(SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(DEPARTMENT_ID),1,1)<>'5'
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
HAVING MAX(SALARY) < 1000;
```

We got the same table so my question is when these two can display different results. I'm aware that data processing is different but as he said that was not the problem. The problem is not is using the INSTR function but not using WHERE.

Comment: Normally u should use only the aggregate function in HAVING

Comment: So that can cause problems?

Comment: check the explain plan of both the queries to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Where clause workn on the raw  contents of the rows
so you filter the dataset that is evaluated  for the select clause

```
 WHERE SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(DEPARTMENT_ID),1,1)<>'5'
```

don't select the rows with

```
SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(DEPARTMENT_ID),1,1)='5'
```

so these rows  are not used for

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, MAX(SALARY) ..GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
```

HAVING work on the result of the selected  result  so also the rows with SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(DEPARTMENT_ID),1,1)='5'  should be processed

in your case each value for the column  DEPARTMENT_ID is always  selected because is mentioned in group by and then both the query should return the same result

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear. Thanks.